# async/await repeats a call unexpectedly

Tags: python, heroku, async-await, discord.py, python-asyncio

So I made this discord bot and hosted it on Heroku. It fetches the latest tweet from a Twitter account and displays it in a specific channel on discord. It works fine most of the time but sometimes it happens that after a few hours, it fetches and displays the first tweet of the Twitter account again, even though there's no new tweet. I used `asyncio.gather()` to tackle this problem and it worked fine but it happened again today. I have been trying to solve this problem but to no avail. What do I do?

```py
    async def send_to_alert(embed):
        await client.get_channel(alert_channel_id).send(content="@everyone", embed=embed)
        return
    
    
    async def send_to_all(embed):
        await client.get_channel(all_channel_id).send(content="@everyone", embed=embed)
        return
    
    
    async def send_to_one(text):
        await client.get_channel(all_channel_id).send(content=f"@everyone\n{text}")
        return

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('Logged in as ' + client.user.name)
        print("Starting to fetch the last tweet from the " + USER_TO_SNITCH + " account")
    
        last_tweet = '0'
    
        while True:
            current_last_tweet = \
            api.user_timeline(screen_name=USER_TO_SNITCH, count=1, include_rts=False, tweet_mode='extended')[0]
            if (int(current_last_tweet.id_str) > int(last_tweet)) and (
                    not current_last_tweet.full_text.startswith('RT')):
                last_tweet = current_last_tweet.id_str
                text = current_last_tweet.full_text
                if "#chart" not in text and "#CHART" not in text and "#Chart" not in text:
                    if "#alert" in text or "#Alert" in text or "#ALERT" in text:
                        embed = alert_found(text)
                        # await send_to_alert(embed)
                        # await send_to_all(embed)
                        await asyncio.gather(send_to_alert(embed), send_to_all(embed))
                    else:
                        await asyncio.gather(send_to_one(current_last_tweet.full_text))
                else:
                    media_link = current_last_tweet.extended_entities["media"][0]["media_url_https"]
                    text = current_last_tweet.full_text.split()
                    text.pop()
                    text = " ".join(text)
                    text = text.replace("#Charts", "").strip()
                    text = text.replace("#CHARTS", "").strip()
                    text = text.replace("#charts", "").strip()
                    text = text.replace("#chart", "").strip()
                    text = text.replace("#Chart", "").strip()
                    text = text.replace("#CHART", "").strip()
                    if text == "":
                        text = " "
                    media_embed = discord.Embed(color=0xffd500, description=f"**{text}**").set_image(url=media_link)
                    await asyncio.gather(client.get_channel(charts_channel_id).send(content="@everyone", embed=media_embed))
    
            time.sleep(10)
    
    
    client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: You keep track of the latest tweet in memory (`last_tweet`). Whenever Heroku restarts your worker that gets reset to `’0’`. If you want that value to survive the restart, you’ll need to use something like a cache (e.g., Redis) or a database (e.g., Postgres). The former is probably more appropriate but Heroku offers the latter for free.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you so much.